# Main Electric Panel Neutral Bar

Tags: neutral, ground

I have a Siemens 200 amp main service panel in my basement.  The main service lines are two black and one black with a yellow stripe going to the neutral bar.  The grounding bar is attached to a ground cable through the bottom of the box to a rod in the basement floor.  All the circuits in this box are 240v/double pole 2-wire breakers (it services another 200 amp panel on the main floor), There are NO wire connections to the neutral bar at all so it appears to me it is not grounded.  I want to install a whole house surge protector in the panel but it's my understanding it must be connected to a grounded neutral bus bar. Do I simply install a jumper from the ground to the neutral bar?

Comment: So you're saying that the ONLY wire that lands on the neutral bus is the incoming wire from the meter, and nothing else (such as a bond to ground, or a wire onward to the subpanel upstairs?)  That sounds very unusual, and possibly dangerous.  Can you post a picture of the inside of the panel?

Comment: Does that other 200amp panel have 120v breakers?  Where is it getting its neutral from?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both panels involved? Something weird is up here...

Comment: It sounds like this panel is wired as a sub panel are there breakers at the meter? If there are breakers at the meter you would not jumper the neutral to ground as that would create a parallel ground path (not code compliant)